# Can Save Method be used to save file with some default file name?

Tags: c#, image

Here is the code:

```
Image.Save("C:\\path\\Image.jpg", ImageFormat.jpeg);
```

I am saving an image from database. My save function is perfectly working. However, here image from database is getting saved with name "image". I want to save it with filename in database. Can someone help me with that?

I am accessing the image from some database table.

Comment: Yes. Just output the name from the database as part of the path.

Comment: Try using the ID of the record to create a unique filename if there is no filename stored in the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

don't know if thats the problem in your case.

for example

```
using System.IO;

var basepath = @"C:/path";
var imageName = "ImageFileNameFromDatabase";
var filename = Path.Combine(basepath, imageName);
if(!File.Exists(filename)){
    Image.Save(filename, ImageFormat.jpeg);
}else{
    //Decide what to do if filename is already taken
}
```

Based on your comments, maybe that one will help you?
here you see how to get the value of specific cells inside a data table
if i understand your post right, you have a data table with 2 columns, Filename and Type.

```
DataTable _dataTable = new Datatable();
//....code that fills your data table...

//Iterate through the rows...
foreach(var row in _dataTable.Rows){

    //access a column by column name
    string imageFileName = row.Field<string>("Filename");

    //its also possible to access a column by index (here column 1 as its zero based)
    string fileNameByIndex = row.Field<string>(0);
}
```

Comment: The thing here is I am not accessing the file from some basepath on my disk. I am accessing it from some database.

Comment: but you know where you want to save the file? Is your problem that there is no filename for the image stored in the database?

Comment: I know where to save the file and also, Filename in Image database I am accessing are available. However, I have used query query that accesses database to give me datatable having columns "FileName, Type". Can I use this datatable somehow to get filenames without extension?

Comment: i´m not sure if i completely understand what you wan´t to do. Please take a look at my edit and see if it helps?